# creating my first image for rocket (serviio with java dependency)

Tags: coreos, rkt, azure-container-instances

I have CoreOS stable (1068.10.0) installed and I want to create a serviio streaming media server image for rocket.

this is my manifest file:

```
{
"acVersion": "1.0.0",
"acKind": "ImageManifest",
"name": "tux-in.com/serviio",
"app": {
"exec": [
    "/opt/serviio/bin/serviio.sh"
],
"user":"serviio",
"group":"serviio"
},
"labels": [
    {
        "name": "version",
        "value": "1.0.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "arch",
        "value": "amd64"
    },
    {
        "name": "os",
        "value": "linux"
    }
],
"ports": [
    {
        "name": "serviio",
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "port": 8895
    }
],
  "mountPoints": [
        {
        "name": "serviio-config",
            "path": "/config/serviio",
        "kind": "host",
            "readOnly": false
        }
    ],
"environment": {
    "JAVA_HOME": "/opt/jre1.8.0_102"
}
}
```

I couldn't find on google how to add java package depenency, so I just downloaded jre, opened it to /rootfs/opt and set a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. is that the right way to go?

welp.. because I configured serviio to run on user and group called serviio, I created /etc/group with `serviio:x:500:serviio` and /etc/passwd with `serviio:x:500:500:Serviio:/opt/serviio:/bin/bash`. is this ok? should I added and configured users differently ?

then I crated a rocket image with `actool build serviio serviio-1.0-linux-amd64.aci`, signed it and ran it with `rkt run serviio-1.0-linux-amd64.aci`. then with `rkt list` i see that the container started and exited immediately.

```
UUID        APP     IMAGE NAME              STATE   CREATED     STARTED         NETWORKS
bea402d9        serviio tux-in.com/serviio:1.0.0        exited  11 minutes ago  11 minutes ago
```

`rkt status bea402d9` returns:

```
state=exited
created=2016-09-03 12:38:03.792 +0000 UTC
started=2016-09-03 12:38:03.909 +0000 UTC
pid=15904
exited=true
app-serviio=203
```

no idea how to debug this issue further. how can I see the output of the sh command that was executed? any other error related information?
have I configured things properly? I'm pretty lost so any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Possibly, serviio could have just daemonized itself and your serviio.sh returned immedately.

Comment: By the way, on serviio download page i see its dependencies: dcraw, ffmpeg etc. Haven't you forgotten to install them inside your container?

Comment: @legeyda - hi. I think I resolved most of the issues. Using acbuild now. https://github.com/kfirufk/tuxin-rkt-acbuild-aci